# Codeigniter put values from db in array and print them

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

All I want is to get some place_ids from db, put them in array and echo that array in view. Could you please check the code below and help me to find the mistake. I think the problem is in view part.

**Model:**

```
$this->db->select('place_id');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('ses_id', $ses_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result_array();
}
else {return false;}
```

**Controller:**

```
$ses_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data["results"] = $this->mymodel->did_get($ses_id);                   
$this->load->view("my_view", $data);
```

**View:**

```
<?php
$place_id = array();
foreach($results as $row){
$place_id[] = $row['place_id'];
}
print_r($place_id);
?>
```

Comment: any error in the view??

Comment: empty page, instead of displaying array elements

Comment: check var_dump($data["results"]); in your controller

Comment: show me your model name

Comment: are you getting any error if yes than show me your error too.

Comment: Are you passing `$ses_id` in model method?

Comment: Tpojka, of course I am

Comment: Yogesh, I do not get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking the $results is empty or not

```
<?php
$place_id = array();
if(!empty($results)
{
   foreach($results as $row)
   {
    $place_id[] = $row['place_id'];
   }
}else
{ echo "no data found";}
print_r($place_id);
?>
```